How to solve a differential equation of the 3rd order without factorisation
I'm just starting with differential equations and I'm having trouble solving the following one:
$\dddot{y} + m\ddot{y} - 2m^3y = 0$
I've determined the characteristic polynomial to be $\lambda^3 + m\lambda^2 -2m^3 = 0$
Normally, I would just factorise or use the abc formula, but I don't understand how to get the 3 solutions to this problem given the constant in the term with the characteristic polynomials.
Any help would be appreciated!

The method you are trying to use only works with linear differential equations with constant coefficients.

So how could I solve this one? And x is a constant, I will change it to m to clarify that.

Therfore $m$ a parameter ?

Yes, exactly, it is.

One of the roots of the characteristic polynomial is $m$.

Thank you! Could you maybe explain why though and how to go from there?

...and the others are $x=(i - 1)m$ and $x = (-i - 1)m$.

Thank you @JeanMarie but how did you derive at that solution? I know how to use complex numbers in differential equations but I still don't understand the first step in solving the problem.

Once you know by inspection that $x=m$ is aroot, just divide the third degree polynomial by $x-m$ giving a quadratic polynomial, then find its roots...

I understand it now - thank you!

$$\dddot{y} + m\ddot{y} - 2m^3y = 0$$
This is ambiguous because the argument of the function $y(?)$ is not defined. Is it $y(x)$ or $y(m)$ or $y(t)$ or what else? The differentials are wrt what variable ?
I suppose that the equation correctly writen is :
$$\frac{d^3 y(t)}{dt^3}+m\frac{d^2 y(t)}{dt^2}-2m^3y(t)=0$$
If the supposition is correct your characteristic polynomial is correct as well.
$$\lambda^3 + m\lambda^2 -2m^3 = 0$$
The three roots are :
$\lambda_1=m\quad$
$\lambda_2=(-1+i)m$
$\lambda_3=(-1-i)m$
Certainly that you can continue.
